# Android Studio Gradle :app:preDexDebug never finishes

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an issue and despite of a lot of googling, i couldn't find any informations about it.
So I have Windows 7 and had Android Studio 1.1 RC Beta and after modifying my code regarding work with a database i got *failure install_failed_dexopt* 
I tried to clean and then to rebuild my project and since that moment Gradle Executing Tasks never finishes if i run my project. I saw into the Gradle logs and here it is

```
Executing tasks: 
[:app:assembleDebug]
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72102Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42102Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
```

I waited ~30 minutes and nothing after that. 
 If i try to stop it, it also never stops, i see only 
`Stopping - Gradle: Executing Tasks[:app:assembleDebug]`
and nothing else
I tried to unistall Android Studio, installed also 1.0.1, I tried to run "hello world" application - is always the same. It would be great if someone have any idea about it, thank you!

Comment: Post your build.gradle. How big is your project? What Gradle version? What Java version? Are you running via commandline or IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seemed to be a problem with sdk. At first I didn't notice, that even if I install Android Studio and sdk into another folder path to sdk was always the same and it was something wrong with that sdk directorie.